# Protractor Using Selenium Grid running IE 10 on Selenium Node

Tags: protractor, selenium-grid

I have a configuration of Selenium Grid, where one of the slaves is Windows machine. I run there 3 browsers (FF, Chrome and IE). First two work very well, but with IE I have issues. After some investigation I found out:
- If to connect to the slave via Remote Desktop and view the session where Slave is running (by means of Interactive Service Detection) everything works perfectly
- If just to run a test and check screenshot (or connecting after some time when test was already executing) I see that first page was opened but all click events just being ignored.

I can understand that problem could be in some permissions given to the user which runs Selenium Node service, but FF and Chrome work with any problem.

Is anybody experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered no end of trouble trying to get selenium to run as a service.  In the end, I set up a secured virtual machine that automatically logs in and runs selenium as a local user.  That way I have a full desktop environment, which is required for the correct operation of Selenium + IE, and I can avoid having a physical console sitting open for anyone who passes by to play with.

Comment: Hi Phil, actually I ended up with the same approach, especially that Selenium says that running IEDriver as a service is not supported https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. Why do you need physical console but not just connect via some "View Tool" and check what is going on?

Comment: You don't need a physical console, you just need a full desktop environment.  Maybe my answer could have been phrased better - I was trying to avoid having a unsecured logged in physical console, which is what the virtual machine gave me.

Comment: true, maybe it is not the best solution, but at least it works :)